# How to get count of repeated entries in columns within a given row, R

Tags: r, organization

I have the given data (smaller than actual set):

| ID | color1 | color2 | color3 | color4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 101 | red | red | blue | green |
| 2 | blue | blue | purple | N/A |
| 400 | yellow | yellow | red | red |

I want a result of:

| ID | red | blue | green | purple | yellow |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 101 | 2 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 2 | 0 | 2 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| 400 | 2 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |

I've tried to use the unique command for a given row, but have been unable to get these results.

Answer (score 0):

```
is.na(df) <- df == 'N/A'
as.data.frame.matrix(table(cbind(df[1], unlist(df[-1]))))

    blue green purple red yellow
2      2     0      1   0      0
101    1     1      0   2      0
400    0     0      0   2      2
```

tidyverse:

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>%
   mutate(across(everything(), na_if, 'N/A')) %>% 
   pivot_longer(-ID, values_drop_na = TRUE) %>%
   count(ID, value) %>%
   pivot_wider(names_from = 'value', values_from = 'n',values_fill = 0)

# A tibble: 3 x 6
     ID  blue purple green   red yellow
  <int> <int>  <int> <int> <int>  <int>
1     2     2      1     0     0      0
2   101     1      0     1     2      0
3   400     0      0     0     2      2
```